Ошибка создания баз данных в PostgreSQL
У меня есть база данных на порту 5432. Я не хочу её менять.
Поэтому, я хочу использовать новый порт для создания базы данных.
Как мне создать ещё одну новую базу данных в pgAdmin (например, на порту 5433)?
Пробовал в postgresql.conf поменять порт на 5433, но в PgAdmin всё равно вылетает ошибка:
Unable to connect server: connection timeout expired
Данные, которые я указываю:
Server- name: News
Connection:
host name: localhost, port: 5433, maintenance database: postgres, username: postgres
Помогите пожалуйста

У меня есть база данных на порту 5432. Сервер БД на 5432 - это понятно. А вот база данных - не бывает. Соответственно Как мне создать ещё одну новую базу данных в pgAdmin (например, на порту 5433)? - это установить ещё один инстанс СУБД, с другим номером используемого порта.
